# Missing sign in Dirac equation

Tags: metric-tensor, conventions, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

This is very trivial, but it's really bugging me. The ansatz for the Dirac equation in terms of $\boldsymbol\alpha$ and $\beta$ matrices is
$$
[i(\partial_t+\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)-\beta m]\psi=0,
$$
and to get the standard form in terms of gamma matrices, one defines $\gamma^\mu=(\beta, \beta\boldsymbol \alpha)$ so that multiplying the equation by $\beta$ gives
$$
[i(\beta\partial_t+\beta\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla)-\beta^2m]=[i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m]=0
$$
as long as the index on $\gamma^\mu$ is *actually* a vector index, which we can make sure of by requiring $\psi$ to transform in the spinor representation. But considering that the correct expansion of the Minkowski product is $$\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu=\gamma^0\partial_0-\boldsymbol\gamma\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla=\beta\partial_t-\beta\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla,$$
shouldn't the expression in the first term be $\beta\partial_t-\beta\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla$, with a minus sign rather than a plus sign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic misuse of the Einstein summation convention. The correct expression in your final equation is
$$
\gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} = \sum_{\mu = 0}^3 \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} = \gamma^0 \partial_0 + \vec{\gamma} \cdot \vec{\nabla}
$$
The reason for your confusion is because you're used to taking the Minkowski inner product between two contravariant or two covariant vectors. If $v^{\mu} = (v^0, \vec{v})$ and $w^{\mu} = (w^0, \vec{w})$, then of course $v^{\mu} w_{\mu} = g_{\mu \nu} v^{\mu} w^{\nu} = v^0 w^0 - \vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}$. But in your expression, $\partial_{\mu}$ is naturally covariant, not contravariant.

Comment: Oh, right. I should have written $\gamma^j\partial_j$ explicitly to see that there was no need to raise the index of $\partial_\mu$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ansatz originally use was to decompose the mass shell relation
$$\frac{E^2}{c^2} = ||^2 + m^2 c^2$$
into linear form as
$$\frac{E}{c} = · + β m c.$$
Under the operator correspondence
$$E ⇔ iħ\frac{∂}{∂t},\quad  ⇔ -iħ∇,$$
and upon application to $ψ$, this becomes:
$$\frac{iħ}{c}\frac{∂ψ}{∂t} = (-i ħ ·∇ + β m c) ψ,$$
or
$$\left(\frac{1}{c}\frac{∂ψ}{∂t} + ·∇\right) ψ = β m c ψ.$$
Thus, upon multiplication by $β$, noting that $β^2 = 1$:
$$\left(β \frac{1}{c}\frac{∂ψ}{∂t} + β ·∇\right) ψ = m c ψ,$$
or just:
$$\left(γ^0 \frac{1}{c}\frac{∂ψ}{∂t} + ·∇\right) ψ = m c ψ,$$
where $γ^0 = β$ and $ = \left(γ^1, γ^2, γ^3\right) = β $.

The signs associated with the operator correspondences reflect the fact that
$$E dt - ·d,$$
is a Lorentz invariant, where $ = (x, y, z)$, so that $(E, )$ transforms as $(∂/∂t, -∇)$, with the extra sign.