# Help understanding Einstein notation

Tags: metric-tensor, notation, dirac-equation

This is basically the same question as [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/629860/). I have the same problem with the sign. In the Dirac equation $(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m)\psi = 0$, the term $i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$ is:
$$i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} = \sum_{j=0}^{3}i\gamma^{j}\partial_{j}$$
However, the Einstein summation convention is being used. The answer of the linked question says that this is because $\partial_{\mu}$ is contravariant; however, I have seen many times $\partial_{\mu}$ being used the sign convention. For instance, the D'Alembertian is:
$$\square^{2} = \partial_{0}^{2}-\partial_{1}^{2}-\partial_{2}^{2}-\partial_{3}^{2} = \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}$$
So, what's the difference here? When do I have to change the signs and when do I not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the metric $[\eta]=\mathrm{diag}(+,-,-,-).$

Note first that

$$X^\mu Y_\mu=X^0Y_0+X^1 Y_1+X^2Y_2+X^3Y_3 \tag{1},$$

but also

$$X^\mu Y_\mu=\eta^{\mu\nu}X_\mu Y_\nu=\eta^{00}X_0Y_0+\eta^{11}X_1Y_1+\eta^{22}X_2Y_2+\eta^{33}X_3Y_3, \tag{2}$$

which, using the components of the metric gives

$$X^\mu Y_\mu=X_0Y_0-X_1Y_1-X_2Y_2-X_3Y_3. \tag{3}$$

Note the position of the indices in $(3)$ compared to $(1)$. We have both indices down in $(3)$ at the cost of introducing factors of $\pm1$ from the Minkowski metric.

Answer (score 3):

The superscript "$2$" on the „Box”/D'Alembertian is superfluous, because the operator is second order in derivatives.

Here is the deal: the "flat" 4D gradient noted by $\partial_{\mu}$ is made up of 4 differential operators $\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^0}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}\right)$, where $x^\mu = \{x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\} =\{t,x,y,z\}$. If the Greek index on the gradient is "downstairs", we call it "covariant", not "contravariant" as you say in your text.

The contraction of the covariant gradient is **necessarily done** with the "upper index Gamma matrices" to properly obey not only Einstein's notation, but also to ensure that no 4D index "floats", i.e. is left free. The flat space-time Minkowski metric used is $g_{\mu\nu} = \left(g^{-1}\right)^{\mu\nu} = \text{diag} (+1,-1,-1,-1)$ and allows you to **simultaneously** raise the Greek index in the gradient and lower the Greek one in the Gamma matrices (equation $(1)$ below).

The Box/D'Alembertian is **in the mostly minus metric** that you propose exactly the one you wrote.

So if everything is done correctly, there is really **no minus sign appearing anywhere explicitly**.

$$\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} = \left(g^{\mu\alpha}\gamma_{\alpha}\right)\left(g_{\mu\sigma}\partial^{\sigma}\right) = \delta^{\alpha}_{\sigma} \gamma_{\alpha}\partial^{\sigma} = \gamma_{\sigma}\partial^{\sigma} \equiv \gamma_{\mu}\partial^{\mu} \tag{1} $$

The only minuses you may see are only on the individual components themselves (because the metric has 3 minuses in the spatial part), but remember that components here are summed over (i.e. the Greek indices are not free). I invite you to expand $(1)$ in individual sums of products:

$$  \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} = \gamma^{0}\partial_{0}+\gamma^{1}\partial_{1}+\gamma^{2}\partial_{2}+\gamma^{3}\partial_{3} \tag{2}$$

Now in order to reach the 5th term of $(1)$ use the metric.

$$ \gamma^{0} = g^{00}\gamma_{0}, ~ \text{etc.} \tag{3}$$

The "non-covariant form of the D'Alembertian" is addressed by Charlie in his reply.